# How to fix "Buffer preloading failed" compute shader performance issue?

Tags: ios, profiling, metal, compute-shader

When capturing a GPU frame from my application I see the following messages under Pipeline Statistics -> Remarks:

> Buffer preloading failed
>
> Make sure your data size is a multiple of 4
> bytes and aligned to 4 bytes and try using a simple access pattern.
> For constant buffers, try using a fixed buffer size.
>
> pointLightBufferCenterAndRadius could not be promoted -
> lightCuller.metal:light_culler

Here's my buffer initialisation:

```
const int MaxLights = 2048;
pointLightCenterAndRadiusBuffer = [GfxDevice::GetMetalDevice() newBufferWithLength:MaxLights * sizeof( Vec4 )
                             options:MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache];
pointLightCenterAndRadiusBuffer.label = @"pointLightCenterAndRadiusBuffer";
```

Here's the relevant portion of my shader:

```
kernel void light_culler(texture2d<float, access::read> depthNormalsTexture [[texture(0)]],
                         constant Uniforms& uniforms [[ buffer(0) ]],
                         constant float4* pointLightBufferCenterAndRadius [[ buffer(1) ]],
                         device uint* perTileLightIndexBufferOut [[ buffer(2) ]],
                         constant float4* spotLightBufferCenterAndRadius [[ buffer(3) ]],
                         uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
                         uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]],
                         uint2 dtid [[threadgroup_position_in_grid]])
{
    threadgroup uint ldsLightIdx[ MAX_NUM_LIGHTS_PER_TILE ];
    threadgroup atomic_uint ldsZMax;
    threadgroup atomic_uint ldsZMin;
    threadgroup atomic_uint ldsLightIdxCounter;

    uint2 globalIdx = gid;
    uint2 localIdx = tid;
    uint2 groupIdx = dtid;

    uint localIdxFlattened = localIdx.x + localIdx.y * TILE_RES;
    uint tileIdxFlattened = groupIdx.x + groupIdx.y * GetNumTilesX( uniforms.windowWidth );

    if (localIdxFlattened == 0)
    {
        atomic_store_explicit( &ldsZMin, 0x7f7fffff, memory_order_relaxed ); // FLT_MAX as uint
        atomic_store_explicit( &ldsZMax, 0, memory_order_relaxed );
        atomic_store_explicit( &ldsLightIdxCounter, 0, memory_order_relaxed );
    }

    float4 frustumEqn[ 4 ];
    {
        uint pxm = TILE_RES * groupIdx.x;
        uint pym = TILE_RES * groupIdx.y;
        uint pxp = TILE_RES * (groupIdx.x + 1);
        uint pyp = TILE_RES * (groupIdx.y + 1);

        float winWidth  = float( TILE_RES * GetNumTilesX( uniforms.windowWidth ) );
        float winHeight = float( TILE_RES * GetNumTilesY( uniforms.windowHeight) );

        float4 v0 = float4( pxm / winWidth * 2.0f - 1.0f, (winHeight - pym) / winHeight * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
        float4 v1 = float4( pxp / winWidth * 2.0f - 1.0f, (winHeight - pym) / winHeight * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
        float4 v2 = float4( pxp / winWidth * 2.0f - 1.0f, (winHeight - pyp) / winHeight * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
        float4 v3 = float4( pxm / winWidth * 2.0f - 1.0f, (winHeight - pyp) / winHeight * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

        float4 frustum[ 4 ];
        frustum[ 0 ] = ConvertClipToView( v0, uniforms.clipToView );
        frustum[ 1 ] = ConvertClipToView( v1, uniforms.clipToView );
        frustum[ 2 ] = ConvertClipToView( v2, uniforms.clipToView );
        frustum[ 3 ] = ConvertClipToView( v3, uniforms.clipToView );

        for (uint i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            frustumEqn[ i ] = CreatePlaneEquation( frustum[ i ], frustum[ (i + 1) & 3 ] );
        }
    }

    threadgroup_barrier( mem_flags::mem_threadgroup );

    float minZ = FLT_MAX;
    float maxZ = 0.0f;

    float depth = depthNormalsTexture.read( globalIdx.xy ).x;

    uint z = as_type< uint >( depth );

    if (depth != 0.0f)
    {
        /*uint i =*/ atomic_fetch_min_explicit( &ldsZMin, z, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
        /*uint j =*/ atomic_fetch_max_explicit( &ldsZMax, z, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
    }

    threadgroup_barrier( mem_flags::mem_threadgroup );

    uint zMin = atomic_load_explicit( &ldsZMin, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
    uint zMax = atomic_load_explicit( &ldsZMax, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
    minZ = as_type< float >( zMax );
    maxZ = as_type< float >( zMin );

    int numPointLights = uniforms.numLights & 0xFFFFu;

    for (int i = 0; i < numPointLights; i += NUM_THREADS_PER_TILE)
    {
        int il = localIdxFlattened + i;

        if (il < numPointLights)
        {
            float4 center = pointLightBufferCenterAndRadius[ il ];
            float radius = center.w;
            center.xyz = (uniforms.localToView * float4( center.xyz, 1.0f ) ).xyz;

            if (-center.z + minZ < radius && center.z - maxZ < radius)
            {
                if ((GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 0 ] ) < radius) &&
                    (GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 1 ] ) < radius) &&
                    (GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 2 ] ) < radius) &&
                    (GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 3 ] ) < radius))
                {
                    // do a thread-safe increment of the list counter
                    // and put the index of this light into the list
                    int dstIdx = atomic_fetch_add_explicit( &ldsLightIdxCounter, 1, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
                    ldsLightIdx[ dstIdx ] = il;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    threadgroup_barrier( mem_flags::mem_threadgroup );

    int numPointLightsInThisTile = atomic_load_explicit( &ldsLightIdxCounter, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );

    // Spot lights.
    int numSpotLights = (uniforms.numLights & 0xFFFF0000u) >> 16;

    for (int i = 0; i < numSpotLights; i += NUM_THREADS_PER_TILE)
    {
        int il = localIdxFlattened + i;

        if (il < numSpotLights)
        {
            float4 center = spotLightBufferCenterAndRadius[ il ];
            float radius = center.w * 5.0f; // FIXME: Multiply was added, but more clever culling should be done instead.
            center.xyz = (uniforms.localToView * float4( center.xyz, 1.0f )).xyz;

            if (-center.z + minZ < radius && center.z - maxZ < radius)
            {
                if ((GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 0 ] ) < radius) &&
                    (GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 1 ] ) < radius) &&
                    (GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 2 ] ) < radius) &&
                    (GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( center, frustumEqn[ 3 ] ) < radius))
                {
                    int dstIdx = atomic_fetch_add_explicit( &ldsLightIdxCounter, 1, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
                    ldsLightIdx[ dstIdx ] = il;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    threadgroup_barrier( mem_flags::mem_threadgroup );

    {   // write back
        int startOffset = uniforms.maxNumLightsPerTile * tileIdxFlattened;

        for (int i = localIdxFlattened; i < numPointLightsInThisTile; i += NUM_THREADS_PER_TILE)
        {
            // per-tile list of light indices
            perTileLightIndexBufferOut[ startOffset + i ] = ldsLightIdx[ i ];
        }

        int jMax = atomic_load_explicit( &ldsLightIdxCounter, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
        for (int j = localIdxFlattened + numPointLightsInThisTile; j < jMax; j += NUM_THREADS_PER_TILE)
        {
            // per-tile list of light indices
            perTileLightIndexBufferOut[ startOffset + j + 1 ] = ldsLightIdx[ j ];
        }

        if (localIdxFlattened == 0)
        {
            perTileLightIndexBufferOut[ startOffset + numPointLightsInThisTile ] = LIGHT_INDEX_BUFFER_SENTINEL;

            int offs = atomic_load_explicit( &ldsLightIdxCounter, memory_order::memory_order_relaxed );
            perTileLightIndexBufferOut[ startOffset + offs + 1 ] = LIGHT_INDEX_BUFFER_SENTINEL;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm debugging the app on an iPad Pro 10.5" using iOS 11.4 and Xcode 9.4. How do I fix the warning?

I also tried to change the buffer's type from `constant float4*` to `constant PointLight& pointLightBufferCenterAndRadius`, where `PointLight` is `struct PointLight { float4 d[ 2048 ]; }` as suggested by Apple's Metal [WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/606/).

Comment: You are simply passing in a pointer to memory for the pointLightBufferCenterAndRadius type, if it is meant to be stored in the constant memory then you should pass a ref to a compile time known constant size item. Also, just FYI that buffer might be too large to fit into constant memory anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is usually not an indication of a catastrophic performance hit.  So resolving this probably won't give you big gains and you may want to look at optimizing other parts of the kernel.

The main way to avoid getting this is by using a [[ stage_in ]] input in your vertex shader or compute kernel to get per vertex/thread data.  This isn't always possible depending on the algorithm used since you may not be able to accessing data "in order" as a [[ stage_in ]] input does.